# Website down - MariaDB failed

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

I had a working website for 2 years, which suddenly stopped working. I haven't performed any updates or upgrades. When I woke up, I noticed that it was not functioning.

I contacted my hosting provider, who informed me that the problem was not on their end. However, they checked the issue for me and provided the following response:

***The issue is that MySQL cannot find the table of plugins 'mysql.plugins'. This problem is common after upgrading or updating MariaDB.***

I am using CyberPanel, OpenLiteSpeed with MariaDB, on Ubuntu 20. OpenLiteSpeed shows as active and running, but MariaDB shows as failed.

```
    lshttpd.service - OpenLiteSpeed HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/lshttpd.service; enabled; vendor prese>
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-06-25 04:41:05 UTC; 3h 9min ago
    Process: 322602 ExecStart=/usr/local/lsws/bin/lswsctrl start (code=exited, >
   Main PID: 322616 (litespeed)
     CGroup: /system.slice/lshttpd.service
             ├─322616 openlitespeed (lshttpd - main)
             ├─322617 openlitespeed (lscgid)
             ├─322618 openlitespeed (lshttpd - #01)
             ├─322619 openlitespeed (lshttpd - #02)
             ├─322620 openlitespeed (lshttpd - #03)
             ├─322621 openlitespeed (lshttpd - #04)
             ├─354870 lsphp
             └─377408 lsphp

Jun 25 04:41:02 kixia systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean terminatio>
Jun 25 04:41:02 kixia systemd[1]: lshttpd.service: Found left-over process >
Jun 25 04:41:02 kixia systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean terminatio>
Jun 25 04:41:02 kixia systemd[1]: lshttpd.service: Found left-over process >
Jun 25 04:41:02 kixia systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean terminatio>
Jun 25 04:41:02 kixia systemd[1]: Starting OpenLiteSpeed HTTP Server...
Jun 25 04:41:02 kixia lswsctrl[322602]: [OK] Send SIGUSR1 to 310608
Jun 25 04:41:05 kixia systemd[1]: Started OpenLiteSpeed HTTP Server.
 lshttpd.service - OpenLiteSpeed HTTP Server



    v Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-06-25 05:08:44 UTC; 3h 7min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 331113 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 331114 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 331116 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl >
    Process: 331166 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 331166 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Jun 25 05:08:43 kixia systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.38 database server...
Jun 25 05:08:44 kixia systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 25 05:08:44 kixia systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 25 05:08:44 kixia systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.38 database server.
```

Log file

```
2023-06-25  5:08:43 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2023-06-25  5:08:43 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2023-06-25  5:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2023-06-25  5:08:44 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2023-06-25  5:08:44 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-06-25  5:08:44 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-06-25  5:08:44 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2023-06-25  5:08:44 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2023-06-25  5:08:44 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Do you have a backup of the database? I cannot tell you the next steps but if you do not want to wait for an answer here: I am quite sure that throwing `InnoDB: Cannot create log files because data files are corrupt` at the search engine of your choice will tell you what to do.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply. I dont have,because it happened when i least expected it.

Comment: Please list the files in the database directory. Don't change them. Copy and paste the result (not as a screenshot) into your question. For example, `ls -lA /var/lib/mysql`. There are some possible answers at https://stackoverflow.com/q/34198735/2344631 but some of them will irretrievably destroy your data so do not guess at fixing your issue with those answers.

Answer (score 0):

The data files the DBMS is trying to start from are toast. Gone. Kaput.

If you're lucky then you were running mysqld from a non-default location (i.e. other than /var/lib/mysql) and the config file you had in place has been overwritten or deleted. You just need to fix the config.

Otherwise, you need to restore from backup.

> I dont have [a backup]

Then you have learnt a valuable lesson.

Create a backup NOW.

Reinstalling Mariadb might work.

> I am using CyberPanel,

You should probably stop doing that too.

Comment: But as the error message says `or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files` you REALLY would expect there to be some tool ("fsck" on DB level) which can (try to) fix this problem. A DB is the app which you would expect to be most resistant against data loss on a crash.

Comment: Yes there are tools. And if you spend a few years learning how to use them you might know how to recover data from a corrupt innodb file which the DBMS can't repair itself. Or you could hire a specialist mysql provider or data forensics provider, but this isn't usually in the same league as single LAMP servers managed via control panels with no backups.

Comment: AND THE VERY FIRST THING THE OP SHOULD DO, BEFORE *ANYTHING* ELSE IS TO BACKUP WHATEVER IS LEFT ON THE FILESYSTEM.

Comment: symcbean thank you very much for the time you spent on me.Its bad news , very very bad news